# Java raw type declaration

Tags: java, generics, compilation, compiler-warnings

Well, there were many question on this site regarding raw types and generics in Java. Even questions regarding why does the next line of code comes up with a warning:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

And answered many times, since ArrayList() is of raw type, therefore the compiler raises a warning since now `list` is not "type safe", and the option to write this line of code is solely for backward compatibility.

What I don't understand, and didn't find questions about it, is why? Since the compiler compiles the Java code by "looking" only on the static references, how come there is a difference in compilation time for writing `new ArrayList();` instead of `new ArrayList<>();`.

For example, writing this code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList(); // 1
list.add("A string"); // 2
list.add(new Object()); // 3
```

results in a compilation warning in line 1, no compilation problem in line 2, but a compilation error in line 3 - of type safety.

Therefore - adding a generic reference to the first line (`new ArrayList<>();`), results only in the removal of the compiler warning.

I understand it's a bad habit to use raw types, but my question is really what is the difference (except for the compilation warning) in writing the right hand side as a raw type.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not care what mechanism created the object that your variable `list` refers to. In fact, it could also refer to `null`. Or it could be a call to a method. Example:

```
void yourMethod() {
    List<String> list = createStringList();
    ...
}

List<String> createStringList() {
    return new ArrayList(); // raw type here
}
```

When having a proper typed variable (that was not declared with a raw type) all usages of this variable are checked against the generic type.

Another thing would be if your variable itself is declared with a raw type: Example:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("A string");
list.add(new Object());
```

This compiles fine, but the warning should alert you because things may break later!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the comparison to other options such as `null` or using methods. So I understand - from the part of "When having a proper..." in your answer, that writing `ArrayList();` instead of `ArrayList<>();` has absolutely no significance and meaning except for the annoying compiliation warning? (of course one should avoid this habit, just for the mere question)

Comment: Well ... as a general rule, you should avoid all warnings (to be as safe as possible). And ... yes ... the statement `List<String> list = new ArrayList()` does no harm to whatever code follows.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have another class where the constructor parameters depend on the type parameter:

```
class Foo<T> {
    Foo(T obj) { }
}
```

Then the compiler checks the parameter type when you create it with a type parameter or diamond operator:

```
 Foo<String> bar = new Foo<>(42); // doesn't compile
```

But raw types turns off generics checking:

```
 Foo<String> bar = new Foo(42); // does compile but causes heap pollution
```

so a warning is necessary.

Comment: Great example! Thanks